# Projection area of spheres in an arbitrary direction

Tags: matlab, math

There is a cluster of spheres of different sizes. If I view them from a certain angle (say, 45 degrees, 45 degrees), some spheres are totally visible to me, some are partially or totally blocked by other spheres. How can I determine which spheres are blocked and which are unblocked? If they are partially blocked, how to calculate the projection area of the unblocked portion in the given direction? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing the best thing to do is to render and count pixels.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I am working on counting points as you said:)